# Have someone a function in SQL that given a initial date, a day number and a final date calculate next matching day number and month?

Tags: sql, datetime, user-defined-functions, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I would like to know if someone have a function in SQL that given a initial date, a day number, a frecuency and a final date calculate next matching day number and month?

For example

```
@initialdate=20130101
@finaldate=20133112
@daynumber=14  --that means every 14
@frecuency=2
```

then the query generate the next dates like this:

```
 20130114
 20130314
 20130514
 20130714
 20130914
 20131114
```

Better if the solution is a CTE, better if validates 28-29 february and when day number is 31.

This is the query i'm working on, its about to generates date given a Type of Frecuency, a frecuency and a ocurrence that depends on the type of frecuency.

```
Type of Frec         Frecuency          Ocurrence
DI (Dairy)           1 (Every 1 day)    na
DI (Dairy)           2 (Every 2 day)    na
..
DI (Dairy)           6 (Every 6 day)    na
SE (Weekly)          1 (Every 1 week)   1   (for Monday)
SE (Weekly)          2 (Every 2 weeks)  3   (for Wednesday)
SE (Weekly)          3 (Every 3 weeks)  5   (for Friday)
SE (Weekly)          4 (Every 4 weeks)  2   (for Tuesday)
MD (Monthly by day)  1 (Every 1 month)  1   (for first day of the month)
MD (Monthly by day)  1 (Every 1 month)  2   (for last day of the month)
...
MD (Monthly by day)  11 (Every 11 months) 2   (for last day of the month)
MF (Monthly by date) 1 (Every 1 month)  14   (for every 14 of the month)
...
MF (Monthly by date) 2 (Every 2 months) 30   (for every 30 of the month)
MF (Monthly by date) 3 (Every 3 months) 31   (for every 31 of the month)
```

Comment: Have you already tried anything at all yourself?  If so, please post your best attempt (even if it failed).

Comment: @PM77-1 Hi, i wrote the code i'm working on and explained a little bit..

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2800/sql-server-function-to-return-a-range-of-dates/  I believe it has almost all you need.